Memory Leak on python logging with FastAPI
I have write a sample to call logger using python FastAPI, but i found that i got memory leek on the server. Did i need to revise my setting?
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

app = FastAPI()

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
    handlers=[
        TimedRotatingFileHandler(f"/log/debug.log", when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=7),
    ]
)

@app.get(f"/")
def test():
    for i in range(1000):
        logging.info("HELLO WORLD")

    return "OK"


The API is hosted on a ubuntu docker server, call by locust, total 7280 request was sent to the server. It run on python3.9 and using latest FastAPI[standard]
Update
I continue to run the load test. And currently, the memory is increasing.

